# How to use (and change) a variable in more than one Slint callback functions in Rust?

Tags: rust, slint

I am learning rust as well as slint. How do I solve the problem where it tells me that folder path does not live enough and considers it borrowed until the end of the main function where it gets dropped?

And make it that I can use folder_path in a different callback function after this one?

I have tried with the variable then mutable references after reading the ownership part of the rust book. But I just can't get out of this problem. Please help. Here is the code:

```
use rfd::FileDialog;

slint::slint! {
    import {Button, VerticalBox } from "std-widgets.slint";

    export component App inherits Window{
        in property <string> current_folder;

        callback choose_folder_clicked <=> choose_folder_btn.clicked;

        VerticalBox {
            Text { text : "Current folder: " + current_folder; }

            choose_folder_btn := Button { text: "Choose folder"; }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut folder_path = String::new();

    let app : App = App::new().unwrap();
    let weak = app.as_weak();

    app.on_choose_folder_clicked( {

        let app : App = weak.upgrade().unwrap();
        let fpr_mut = &mut folder_path;

        move || {
            let folder = FileDialog::new()
                .set_directory("/")
                .pick_folder();

            match folder { 
                Some(f) => *fpr_mut = f.clone().into_os_string().into_string().unwrap().into(), 
                None => (),
            }
        }
    }
    );

    app.run().unwrap();
}
```

After this, I would like to add an another button that opens the folder remembered inside the folder_path variable so I cant use the variable itself in the first function and move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure for `app.on_choose_folder_clicked` is expected to have a static lifetime, but since it captures `&mut folder_path`, it's in fact tied to the life time of `main()`. This will lead to compile errors.

There are different solutions to this, but I think the most common one is to share the data via `Rc` and use interior mutability when trying to access the data. Like here for example with `AppState`: https://github.com/slint-ui/slint/blob/3ad3a4265684f22a74877aadf330667d2310388b/examples/slide_puzzle/main.rs#L176

Each closure captures a clone of the Rc

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helped a lot, as well as the example you gave me. For anyone else looking to solve their problem. Here is the maybe not very pretty but working code:

Answer (score 0):

```
use rfd::FileDialog;
use std::{borrow::{Borrow, BorrowMut}, rc::Rc};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;


slint::slint! {
    import {Button, VerticalBox } from "std-widgets.slint";

    export component App inherits Window{
        in property <string> current_folder;

        callback choose_folder <=> choose_folder_btn.clicked;
        callback open_folder <=> open_folder_btn.clicked;

        VerticalBox {
            Text { text : "Current folder: " + current_folder; }

            choose_folder_btn := Button { text: "Choose folder"; }

            open_folder_btn := Button { text: "Open folder"; }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let folder_path = Rc::new(RefCell::new(String::from("")));

    let app : App = App::new().unwrap();
    let weak = app.as_weak();

    let mut fp_copy = folder_path.clone();

    app.on_choose_folder( {
        let app : App = weak.upgrade().unwrap();

        move || {
            let folder = FileDialog::new()
                .set_directory("/")
                .pick_folder();

            match folder { 
                Some(f) => { (*fp_copy.borrow_mut()).replace(f.clone().into_os_string().into_string().unwrap()); 
                                        app.set_current_folder(f.clone().into_os_string().into_string().unwrap().into()); }, 
                None => (),
            };
        }
    }
    );

    let fp_copy = folder_path.clone();
    app.on_open_folder( move || {
        //let app : App = weak.upgrade().unwrap();     
        let paths = fs::read_dir(Path::new::<str>(&(*<RefCell<String> as Clone>::clone(&fp_copy).into_inner()))).unwrap();

        for path in paths {
            println!("Name: {}", path.unwrap().path().display())
        }
    }
    );

    app.run().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).